# Quartz.Net TriggerJob and wait for execution

Tags: .net, quartz.net, quartz, quartz.net-3.0

I need to manually invoke some Quartz.NET jobs and wait for them to complete. Please see the simplified sample code below:

```
[HttpPost("[action]/{jobKey}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> StartJob(string jobKey)
{
    await _schedulerService.Scheduler.TriggerJob(new Quartz.JobKey(jobKey)); 
    return Ok();
}
```

However, using TriggerJob will not wait also for the execution of the job itself to complete. Is it possible to achieve this using Quartz.NET? I am using it on .NET Core, with the following package:

```
 <PackageReference Include="Quartz" Version="3.0.7" />
```

Comment: May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68762715/manually-triggering-and-waiting-for-quartz-net-job) is an answer to this question also?